Type cast for dynamic array of class
I have the following code:
  TBase = class
  end;

  TBaseArray = array of TBase;

  TDerived = class(TBase)
  end;

  TDerivedArray = array of TDerived;

  procedure DoSomething(const BaseArray: TBaseArray);
  function DerivedArrayToBaseArray(const DerivedArray: TDerivedArray): TBaseArray;
  procedure Test;

var
  BaseArray: TBaseArray;
  DerivedArray: TDerivedArray;

implementation

procedure DoSomething(const BaseArray: TBaseArray);
begin
end;


function DerivedArrayToBaseArray(const DerivedArray: TDerivedArray): TBaseArray;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(DerivedArray));
  for var i := Low(DerivedArray) to High(DerivedArray) do
    Result[i] := DerivedArray[i] as TBase;
end;


procedure Test;
begin
  DoSomething(BaseArray);
  DoSomething(DerivedArray); { Error E2010 Incompatible types: 'TBaseArray' and 'TDerivedArray' }
  DoSomething(TBaseArray(DerivedArray)); { Works }
  DoSomething(DerivedArrayToBaseArray(DerivedArray)); { Works }
end;

DoSomething(DerivedArray) expectably does not compile with error E2010 Incompatible types.
DoSomething(TBaseArray(DerivedArray)) compiles and seems to work correctly. I am just wondering, if this hard typecast can cause problems in special situations?
DoSomething(DerivedArrayToBaseArray(DerivedArray)) is a safe possibility and works. However, it is relatively slow and gets tedious in the case of multiple derived classes.
Can I generally use the hard typecast TBaseArray(DerivedArray), or should I better use something more safe?

FWIW, I use constructs like your DoSomething(TBaseArray(DerivedArray)) when the array is const and never noticed any problems. AFAICT the only problem is that the compiler doesn't know enough about co-/contravariance to allow the conversion without an explicit cast.

Indeed, this should be perfectly valid, as long as you don't mess up your cast. (Also, you don't need your as TBase.)

Make the generic function or use TValue type as a parameter.
  TArrayUtils = class
    class function TArrayCast<T,R>(AArray: TArray<T>): TArray<R>;
    class function TArrayCast<R>(AArray: TValue): TArray<R>;
...

class TArrayUtils.TArrayCast<T,R>(AArray: TArray<T>): TArray<R>;
begin
  Result := (R(@AArray)^);
end;
// TArrayUtils.TArrayCast<TDerivedArray, TBaseArray>(DerivedArray)

or
class TArrayUtils.TArrayCast<R>(AArray: TValue): TArray<R>;
begin
  Result := AArray.AsType<TArray<R>>;
end;
// TArrayUtils.TArrayCast<TBaseArray>(DerivedArray)

Unfortunately, there is no other way to do this without casting the information. I recommend that you just do DoSomething(TBaseArray(DerivedArray)); which is more practical and faster.
Unless you use a custom Records. https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Custom_Managed_Records
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi)
